# MoveTo SKAction forever

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I have the following code to move an "enemy" to my "players" position.

```
let follow = SKAction.moveTo(player.position, duration: 2)
enemy.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(action), withKey: "moving")
```

This code works fine. However, when I move the player, I would like the SKAction to "run again" so that the enemy is always moving towards the last location that the player was at. Therefore, if the player does not keep moving, they will eventually get caught.

How come the "repeatActionForever" is not working? The enemy moves to the initial location of the player, but when you move the player to a new location, the enemy does not move to that new location.

Thanks :D

Comment: When you move the player you use: enemy.removeAllActions, then run the "follow" action again.

Comment: how is movement determined, is it 2 directional(Up/Down) 4 directional(Up/Down/Left/Right), 8 directional (U/D/L/R, all corners) or omni directional (Free to go any direction)

Answer (score 0):

`repeatActionForever` is working,  it is not dynamic,  it will only move to the player at the time the action was created, it does not know anything has changed.

You need to do `runBlock` for this:

```
let follow = 
SKAction.sequence(
 [
   SKAction.runBlock(
   {
     //this will allow the enemy to constantly follow the player
     enemy.runAction(SKAction.moveTo(player.position, duration: 2), withKey:"move")
   }),
   SKAction.waitForDuration(0.1)
 ]
)
enemy.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(follow), withKey: "moving")
```

Now the problem with this approach is your enemy speed changes based on the distance of the player.  Instead you want to do this:

```
//duration is expected time to reach the player
let follow = SKAction.customActionWithDuration(duration,
    actionBlock: 
    {
      node,elapsedTime in
      //change the nodes velocity
      //this formula is dependent on gameplay
    })

enemy.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(follow), withKey: "moving")
```

Comment: @KnightOfDragon Actually this will not work. The action to be repeated must have a non-instantaneous duration. SKAction.runBlock has an instantaneous effect...

Comment: @KnightOfDragon You could repeat an action sequence forever, like this : SKAction.sequence([delay, follow]) and it will work. But, still, I am not sure I would use SKActions for all this and probably the choice would be an update: method, but this depends on what OP really wants to achieve (which isn't clearly stated IMO).

Comment: @Whirlwind. we wouldn't want to wait,  we want to constantly update the moveTo based on the players position, regardless if the move completed or not,  I thought that with the key, it will do the cancel for us when replacing the action, but if the action still continues, then we need to add the removeAction manually beforehand

Comment: @Whirlwind this is why I would do my second method with changing the velocity based on player position, but I would need to know how the enemy is expected to be moving.

Comment: @KnightOfDragon The point is that you can't run a block of code and repeat it forever like you are doing right now. It's the same as while(1). It's an infinite loop.

Comment: @Whirlwind  I see what you are saying now,  it will get stuck in the update phase with no chance to escape because as it immediately finishes it will launch again,  I will update my answer

Comment: @KnightOfDragon Yup. That's the catch... There are always a lot of things to discuss when it comes to actions or blocks,  but comments are not suitable for that because we could easily go off-topic :) But, if you are by any chance interested in further discussion, feel free to email me, so I can send you an invite to join SpriteKitAlliance to continue conversation in our Slack group.

Comment: Thanks for all the inputs guys. I actually made it so that each time the player moves the block will move towards the location the player moves to. Even though this is unorthodox (no constant speed etc) it actually suits my game really well. 

Thanks again for all the discussions. It helped a lot!